# dask - merge/full cartesian product - memory issue

Tags: python, dask

I have a dask dataframe and need to compare all the values in one column to all the values in the same column. Eventually I will be using a function on these value pairs, but for now I'm just trying to get the .merge to work. Example code:

```
my_dd['dummy'] = 1
my_dd = my_dd.merge(my_dd, how='inner', on='dummy', npartitions=100000)
print(str(len(my_dd)))
```

At this point my starting data set is pretty small - my_dd before the join has about 19K rows. So after the join, there going to be about 360 million rows.

The above code gives me a memory error. Running on a single machine / LocalCluster with 32GB ram. With specifying nparitions, the code seems like it will work but eventually fails partway through (when most of the graph tasks are mostly complete).

I realize the problem here is the massive resulting df, but I would imagine there is some solution. Have done a lot of digging and can't find anything.

Comment: Can you try `my_dd.head()`, if it works, then the merge works fine, but `len` might be trying to keep too many partitions in memory at once.

Comment: That makes sense and it runs very fast. But oddly, I get: UserWarning: Insufficient elements for `head`. 5 elements requested, only 0 elements available. Try passing larger `npartitions` to `head`.
  warnings.warn(msg.format(n, len(r))).   Not sure how its possible for no rows to be in the result of the .merge (in any number of partitions).

Comment: FWIW - I just upgraded from  2021.6.2 to 2021.7.0 and now I get the same behavior noted above when creating the df with .from_pandas. However, if I use read_csv I get: ValueError: Mismatched dtypes found in `pd.read_csv`/`pd.read_table`. Column                    | Found  | Expected -->Special Processing Health | object | float64

Comment: And in either case, I can successfully use dd.head() before the merge and the data looks fine.

Comment: If I reduce the size of the starting df to 1/4 it's size, I can get .head() after the merge to work. It fails when the original df is as big as 1/2 its original size. Have also tried variations of npartitions in from_pandas() and in .merge(). But still could not get it work when bigger than 1/4 the original size.

Comment: I ran the code using a cluster with two machines, each 32GB of RAM. Was able to then get .head() to work using the entire starting data set and was then also able to get len() of the whole df. Would be nice to get this to work on a single machine but the noted approach will work for now. Thanks @SultanOrazbayev.